# Troubleshooting: Why Doesn't My Function Enter the Try/Catch Block?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vuex

While working with `Vuex`, I encountered an issue in a particular section where I'm making a GET request to my API. Despite knowing that the response should be a 404 error, my code doesn't seem to enter the try-catch block when this happens at the line

```
var rptReq = await investigacionApi.get(url);
```

. I even attempted to nest two sets of try-catch blocks, but the behavior remained the same.

```
export const getUserByEmail = async ({ commit }, { dni, password }) => {
  var path = `/api/usuarios/dni`;
  try {
    const params = { dni, password };
    const url = `${path}?${new URLSearchParams(params)}`;
    console.log(url)
    try {
      var rptReq = await investigacionApi.get(url);
      console.log(rptReq)
      if (!rptReq || !rptReq.data) {
        throw new Error('La respuesta recibida es inválida');
      }
      const { status, data } = rptReq.data;
      commit('setUserProvider', { status, data, message: null })
    } catch (errores) {
      const { status, error } = errores.response.data;
      commit('setUserProvider', { status, data: null, message: error })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    commit('setUserProvider', { status: false, data: null, message: "error.message" })
  }
}
```

[image]

The screenshot displays my console error, indicating that my code broke on line 29, which corresponds to the API GET request. However, when I tested the same scenario in POSTMAN, I received a 404 response with a body.

And this is my investigacionApi.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
const apiUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL;
const investigacionApi = axios.create({
    baseURL: apiUrl
})

export default investigacionApi
```

Comment: Does `investigacionApi.get` _throw_ any exceptions, when anything goes wrong?

Comment: 404 is not an error, it's a state.

Comment: Seeing red lines in console doesn't necessary mean there is an error thrown. It only means something is logged with `console.error()`

Comment: @CBroe I added a picture to illustrate the error. However, the try-catch block does not capture this error.

Comment: @KevinMontañezHuamán Becuase it might or might not be an error depending on how `investigacionApi` is implemented. Show its implementation if you can.

Comment: note that your code checks : `if (!rptReq || !rptReq.data) { ...` in order to throw an error. The condition does _not_ check whether the return status indicates a success, so a 404 with a body will not trigger your `throw new Error(...)`. Also : you show a capture of an error message in the console, javascript code may log an error (e.g: call `console.error(...some message...)`) without raising an exception.

Comment: For a regular `fetch()` call, 404 is not an error, it is a successful request with a response of status 404. An error would mean you doesn't get a response at all, like when there is no internet. If you want to throw an error when 404 is received, you have to explicitly check the response status code and throw an error.

Comment: It always depends on what `investigacionApi.get` (or whatever communicates with the API/REST endpoint) considers a throw/reject. Most libraries doing API/REST requests differentiate between communication layer errors (no or ill-formed response received), which results in a throw/reject, and valid responses from the API. A valid response from the API can have an error state like 404, but it is still a valid response (it is a response that tells you that the resource was not found). So you have to build you own logic around that.

Comment: So with axios, it should automatically throws when encounter 404. I suspect it is actually throwing in the inner try/catch. Now the question is what does `commit` do? Since you doesn't `console.log` in the inner catch block, what make you think that it "does not  enter the catch block"?

Comment: Put a `console.log(errores);` inside the inner catch block and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue here, actually `404` is not `error or exception` it's a `status code`. That's why it will not goes into `catch block`.

Instead you can try this

```
export const getUserByEmail = async ({ commit }, { dni, password }) => {
  var path = `/api/usuarios/dni`;
  try {
    const params = { dni, password };
    const url = `${path}?${new URLSearchParams(params)}`;
    console.log(url)
    try {
      var rptReq = await investigacionApi.get(url);

      // check here for specific scenario from the rptReq.

      console.log(rptReq)
      if (!rptReq || !rptReq.data) {
        throw new Error('La respuesta recibida es inválida');
      }
      const { status, data } = rptReq.data;
      commit('setUserProvider', { status, data, message: null })
    } catch (errores) {
      const { status, error } = errores.response.data;
      commit('setUserProvider', { status, data: null, message: error })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    commit('setUserProvider', { status: false, data: null, message: "error.message" })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, [axios throws an error when the response status code is not within  the 2xx range](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config#:%7E:text=return%20status%20%3E%3D%20200%20%26%26%20status%20%3C%20300%3B%20//%20default)

Your code looks like this.

```js
try
{
   try
   {
      throw new Error("Hi");  
   }
   catch(innerErr)
   {
       console.log("inner");
       console.error(innerErr);
   }
}
catch(err)
{
    console.log("outer");
    console.error(innerErr);
}
```

You can see only "inner" is printed. Because the error is properly handled by the inner try-catch block and not getting re-thrown. Error happens within the inner try-catch block will never get thrown to the outer try-catch block.